# gradle spring-boot bootDistTar custom scripts into tar package

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

The default behavior of gradle application plugin is to create the package with `/bin` and `/lib`, which contain startup scripts (bash + .bat) and the boot jar respectively.

Here is what I need:

- Have my own custom startup script (that saves the PID somewhere etc). The default one created based on `resources/unixStartScript.txt` which is overkill for my needs.
- Suppress the creation of the `.bat` script. It's just garbage and the people from the linux deployment team that I have to hand over the `.tar` distribution file will reject the tar because of unnecessary content.
- In addition to the custom start script, I also need a few others such as stop script, status, etc.

So far, I was only able to accomplish my first bullet point by doing:

```
bootStartScripts {
    unixStartScriptGenerator.template = resources.text.fromFile('scripts/start.sh.template')
}
```

But that doesn't prevent the windows script to be generated. I also tried `windowsStartScriptGenerator = null` but that breaks, and also tried:

```
windowsStartScriptGenerator = new ScriptGenerator() {
    void generateScript(JavaAppStartScriptGenerationDetails details, Writer dest) {
    }
}
```

...but that last attempt only made the windows script contents to be blank but file still there.

Is there a way to simply override the `bootStartScripts` definition so it just points to a bunch of files in my project (`scripts/*.sh`), process them as templates and put them (and only them) under `/bin` of the `.tar` file?

Comment: If you want to completely change the contents of the distribution tarball, your best bet is probaly to avoid using the application plugin, and to simply add a task of type Tar (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html), and include whatever you want in the generated tarball.

Comment: I still wanted to take advantage of templating (replacing variables with project values during build times). :(